# How to write byte-wise to file in C++

Tags: c++, c

I want to write to a binary file in C++ at specified file positions such that I write to the file 1-5 byte at a time. I have a list of integers:

5 9 10 11 76 98 99999

Which I want to store in the file byte-wise. Such that at the values get stored in the file in the following form:

```
filepointerWriter, 5
filepinterWriter+2, 9
filepinterWriter+8, 10
filepinterWriter+12, 76
filepinterWriter+16, 10 etc
```

I know how to write to a file like:

```
ofstream f("f", ios::out | ios::binary);
f << 5; f << 9; f << 10; f << 76; // etc.
```

But I am not getting how should I write to a file byte-wise.

Comment: What do you mean by "byte-wise"? Every operation/class/function writes and reads bytes, you know?

Comment: Do you want to write the strings `"5"`, `"9"`,  ... or the integer values `5`, `9`, ... to a file?

Comment: I think he/she means binary. I would simply forget about C++ here and use `write()`, but that's just my simple mind...

Comment: 0-2-8-12-16? What kind of [sequence](http://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C2%2C8%2C12%2C16&language=english&go=Search) is that? ;)

Comment: I suppose you meant to write `filepinterWriter+4` in the second line instead of `filepinterWriter+2`?

Comment: @interjay Even if i assume filepointerWriter+4 my question remains the same

Comment: Research `seekg` and `seekp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using pointers and memcpy, for example:

lets say that you want to store the following:

```
--------------------------------------------
|   bytes 0-3  |  bytes 4-5   | bytes 6-9  |
|      9       |     10       |     15     |
--------------------------------------------


int int1 = 9;
short short1 = 10;
int int2 = 15;

const int num_bytes = 10; // total bytes in the array
char str[num_bytes];
ZeroMemory(str, num_bytes);  // this will write zeros in the array

memcpy((void *)(str + 0), &int1, 4);    // length of integer 4 bytes
memcpy((void *)(str + 4), &short1, 2);  // length of short 2 bytes
memcpy((void *)(str + 6), &int2, 4);    // length of integer 4 bytes
```

then you can write the "str" variable using any method you want.